# adding & to a URL query string in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, parameters

I have an application that sometimes has a query string in the URL and sometimes does not, depending on the user.

So, usually the URL is `www.website.com/application/main-page`. However, on this main-page I have tabs that are retained by adding parameters in the query string like so: `main-page?defaultTab=1`. This works great. But not if the URL already has parameters.

If the URL already has parameters, for example `main-page?customerID=1` then the tabs are not retained because the `?defaultTab=1` does not get appended to the URL correctly. I need it to append to the URL with the correct syntax of `main-page?customerID=1&defaultTab=1`.

How can I check to see if the query string is not null? Then, if not null, add & rather than ?.   ?

I've tried variations of this, but cant get it to work:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["customerID"]))
{
     Request.QueryString.Add ("&");
}
```

Comment: you aren't expecting querystring values to be in a specific location of the querystring, are you? so,  you just need to append something to the end of the querystring if it exists, or create the querystring if it does not?

Comment: exactly. I really just need to append something to the end of the querystring if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

[Request.QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) is not a `string` but a NameValueCollection which is an reference type.

[NameValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx)

> Represents a collection of associated String keys and String values
>   that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

Request.QueryString property is auto populated, thus you can just add elements to it, without considering how many if any keys it has.

```
Request.QueryString["customerID"] = "1";
Request.QueryString["defaultTab"] = "1";
```

This will auto generate the request string you need.

Comment: As well as Request.QueryString, It isn't allowed ?

Comment: @mason, Fixed, but on NameValueCollection i wanted it right next the explanation.

Comment: "but a NameValueCollection which is an object." **Everything** in C# is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set()` method of querystring to set a new key/value pair altogether.  Like

```
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection QS = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
        QS.Set("defaultTab", "1");
        string updatedQueryString = "?" + QS.ToString();
```

Comment: I'm wondering why are you casting a string to a string... QueryString[string] already **is** a string

Comment: That's right and edited but even if you have such code that generally gets ignored. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`:

```
string initialUrl = "www.yourwebsite.com";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
Request.QueryString["customerID"] = "yourValue";
var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString);
uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
yourUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```